# How do I select specific values in column and add character before

Tags: python, pandas

How could I select in column 'Funding' all the values ending with "M" and then eliminate M,$  and add "0," before value.

ex. from $535M to 0,535

That's beacuase I have Billion and Million values, I've decided to formatting the column in billion so, values in millions must be 0,...

[image: Here is the example. Df is Unicors companies from Kaggle]

```
df.head(10).to_dict()
```

> {'Company': {0: 'Bytedance',
> 1: 'SpaceX',
> 2: 'SHEIN',
> 3: 'Stripe',
> 4: 'Klarna',
> 5: 'Canva',
> 6: 'Checkout.com',
> 7: 'Instacart',
> 8: 'JUUL Labs',
> 9: 'Databricks'},
> 'Valuation': {0: '$180B',
> 1: '$100B',
> 2: '$100B',
> 3: '$95B',
> 4: '$46B',
> 5: '$40B',
> 6: '$40B',
> 7: '$39B',
> 8: '$38B',
> 9: '$38B'},
> 'Date Joined': {0: '2017-04-07',
> 1: '2012-12-01',
> 2: '2018-07-03',
> 3: '2014-01-23',
> 4: '2011-12-12',
> 5: '2018-01-08',
> 6: '2019-05-02',
> 7: '2014-12-30',
> 8: '2017-12-20',
> 9: '2019-02-05'},
> 'Industry': {0: 'Artificial intelligence',
> 1: 'Other',
> 2: 'E-commerce & direct-to-consumer',
> 3: 'Fintech',
> 4: 'Fintech',
> 5: 'Internet software & services',
> 6: 'Fintech',
> 7: 'Supply chain, logistics, & delivery',
> 8: 'Consumer & retail',
> 9: 'Data management & analytics'},
> 'City': {0: 'Beijing',
> 1: 'Hawthorne',
> 2: 'Shenzhen',
> 3: 'San Francisco',
> 4: 'Stockholm',
> 5: 'Surry Hills',
> 6: 'London',
> 7: 'San Francisco',
> 8: 'San Francisco',
> 9: 'San Francisco'},
> 'Country': {0: 'China',
> 1: 'United States',
> 2: 'China',
> 3: 'United States',
> 4: 'Sweden',
> 5: 'Australia',
> 6: 'United Kingdom',
> 7: 'United States',
> 8: 'United States',
> 9: 'United States'},
> 'Continent': {0: 'Asia',
> 1: 'North America',
> 2: 'Asia',
> 3: 'North America',
> 4: 'Europe',
> 5: 'Oceania',
> 6: 'Europe',
> 7: 'North America',
> 8: 'North America',
> 9: 'North America'},
> 'Year Founded': {0: 2012,
> 1: 2002,
> 2: 2008,
> 3: 2010,
> 4: 2005,
> 5: 2012,
> 6: 2012,
> 7: 2012,
> 8: 2015,
> 9: 2013},
> 'Funding': {0: '$8B',
> 1: '$7B',
> 2: '$2B',
> 3: '$2B',
> 4: '$4B',
> 5: '$572M',
> 6: '$2B',
> 7: '$3B',
> 8: '$14B',
> 9: '$3B'},
> 'Select Investors': {0: 'Sequoia Capital China, SIG Asia Investments, Sina Weibo, Softbank Group',
> 1: 'Founders Fund, Draper Fisher Jurvetson, Rothenberg Ventures',
> 2: 'Tiger Global Management, Sequoia Capital China, Shunwei Capital Partners',
> 3: 'Khosla Ventures, LowercaseCapital, capitalG',
> 4: 'Institutional Venture Partners, Sequoia Capital, General Atlantic',
> 5: 'Sequoia Capital China, Blackbird Ventures, Matrix Partners',
> 6: 'Tiger Global Management, Insight Partners, DST Global',
> 7: 'Khosla Ventures, Kleiner Perkins Caufield & Byers, Collaborative Fund',
> 8: 'Tiger Global Management',
> 9: 'Andreessen Horowitz, New Enterprise Associates, Battery Ventures'}}

I did a similar manipulation with Valuation, here is how I did. I hope it's right.

```
df['Valuation'] = df['Valuation'].str.replace(
    "B","").str.replace(
    "$","").astype(int)
```

I've tried in several way but none of them works. Here are some of them:

```
df['Funding'] = np.where(df.Funding.str.contain("M"), 
                         df['Funding'] = ('0,'+ df['Funding']),
                        pass)
```

```
df['Funding'] = df['Funding'].str.replace(
    "B", "").str.replace(
    "$","").str.replace(
    "M","0,")
```

```
if df['Funding'].str.contains("M").any():
    df['Funding'] = df['Funding'].str.replace("M", "")
```

```
asd = "M"
if any(("M" in asd) for M in df['Funding']):
    df['Funding'].join((df['Funding'][:0],'0,',df['Funding'][0:])) and replace("M", "")
```

Thank to all who want to help me. It's my first time with Python, I'm more familiare with R

Comment: please provide a sample of the DataFrame as **text**

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your column values in billions, you can use:

```
df["Valuation"] = df["Funding"].str[1:-1].astype(int).where(df["Funding"].str.endswith("B"),df["Funding"].str[1:-1].astype(int).div(1000))

>>> df
  Funding  Valuation
0     $8B      8.000
1     $2B      2.000
2   $535M      0.535
```

###### Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Funding": ["$8B", "$2B", "$535M"]})
```

Comment: Then provide a better sample of your data using `df.head(10).to_dict()`. This works on dummy input.

Comment: I added to_dict()

Comment: df['Funding'] = np.where(df["Funding"].str.endswith("M"),df["Funding"].str.replace("$","0,"), df["Funding"].str.replace("$",""))

I did it, thank you!!